# What is the minimum Mac OS version for Tensorflow 1.0.0?

Tags: macos, installation, tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow on my Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite) system, with Python 3.6. This failed with the message:

`pip install tensorflow --user
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

There is of course a [`tensorflow 1.0.0` package on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.0.0).  There is no requirement for macOS version number listed on that page, but the installable "whale" files have names like `tensorflow-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl`.

I suspect that the "`10_11`" notation means that one must have Mac OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" or higher to install, but I can't find a statement to that effect.

The [Tensorflow Mac installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) are silent on macOS version requirements.  They also direct us to ask installation questions here on SO. The optional [nVidia CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) library seems to require 10.11 or higher.

Can anyone give a definitive answer?

Comment: In `Python 3.x` you would normally use `pip3 install tensorflow`...

Comment: Official binaries are Python 3.5 only, although on MacOS a simple renaming of wheel will trick it to work with Python 3.6 -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6533

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I see a TensorFlow .whl file named with [cp36](https://pypi.python.org/packages/65/a3/40bbfb783d955c1a959c8fa939f63b00d4fac9d0c3777e0607d39e31ba0a/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl#md5=5926a0360b2979cb969e8c38a18f9c0a). This is for Python 3.6, correct?

Comment: Yes that should work

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command instead on a mac:
pip3 install tensorflow-macos

By default it will install tensorflow-2 though

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is: what is the definitive answer to whether one must have Mac OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" or higher to install tensorflow 1.0.0?